ease of dehydration

ease of dehydration for the following alcohols is?
I understand the most easiest would be for III, but shouldn't it be easier for I than for II? because II forms an anti aromatic compound?
But the answer is III>II>I

There are certain conditions we have to check before using the 4n rule to classify the compound as aromatic or anti-aromatic.
One of the conditions required is that the electron density should delocalize over the entire ring. In the carbocation formed by the second compound, the electron density would delocalize only over half the ring thus the compound is not anti-aromatic.
Instead, the carbocation achieves higher stability than the one in I as it is stabilized by resonance with the double bond.
The order would be III>II>I, as the source suggests.
